# jQuery not working in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, mobile-safari

I've got this jquery script, it seems to be working in other browser, but it doesnt work at all in Safari. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Its supposed to be accessed from an iphone.

url: http://connectsr.org.nz/calendar/

thanks

Comment: Works fine for me in Safari 5

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Jquery script is not working on the mobile perfectly. Instead of jquery, you can use jquery mobile (http://jquerymobile.com/)

Comment: actually you need JQuery in order to use JQuery Mobile, you cannot use it 'instead'.

Comment: How does answer like that get accepted? ugh - just sends out the wrong message completely to anyone who stumbles across this question for their own means.

Answer (score 0):

in safari 5 on windows 7 this works, but not with my iphone (iphone 4 with newest ios, not jailbreaked). i think this is because if you click and drag to scroll the colums, the safari on the iphone tries to scroll the site (which is what it normally does when you klick and drag on a website)